# Accessing a DLL in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, dll, vba

I am trying to access a function from VBA, in a Dll that has the following info:

```
typedef struct I1_Device_* I1_DeviceHandle
```

An opaque datatype representing a handle to an i1 device.

A handle of this type can be obtained by calling `I1_GetDevices`.

This device handle is used to perform operations on a specific device instance. When finished with the device handle, you should call `I1_CloseDevice`.

Function Documentation:

```
I1_API I1_ResultType I1_GetDevices( I1_DeviceHandle ** devices,
                                    0I1_UInteger * count );
```

> Get a pointer to an array of device handles for devices currently
>   connected to the computer.
>
> Parameters
>       [out] devices a pointer to an internal static array of device handles
>       [out] count   number of entries in the array
>
> Returns
>       eNoError on success
>
> Each handle represents a connected device. A handle becomes invalid if
>   the device is closed or disconnected. Each subsequent call of
>   I1_GetDevices will invalidate the array returned by the previous call.
>   The last entry in the array is a NULL pointer. The memory used by the
>   array is maintained by the library, so do not attempt to free this
>   memory. The number of entries in the array is returned in count.
>
> The handles returned in this array are not valid to use in most APIS
>   until opened by a call to I1_OpenDevice. You do not need to call
>   I1_CloseDevice on the handles returned in the array unless you have
>   explicitly opened them via I1_OpenDevice

.

**I believe that the problem is in the declare statement about the opaque data type.  I have tried the following:

```
Public Declare Function I1_GetDevices Lib "C:\i1Pro.dll" (ByVal I1_DeviceHandle,
                                                          ByVal I1_UInteger)
               As Variant
```

And get an error 49.  Any help?**

Comment: Something looks strange about the code you've posted. It would seem to make more sense that either the declaration of `I1_GetDevices` should be `I1_API I1_ResultType I1_GetDevices( I1_DeviceHandle * devices, I1_UInteger * count );` or the `I1_DeviceHandle` type should be declared as `typedef struct I1_Device_ I1_DeviceHandle`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `I1_ResultType` is an integer type, try this declaration in VBA:

```
Public Declare Function I1_GetDevices Lib "C:\i1Pro.dll" _
    (ByRef handles as Long, ByRef count as Long) As Long
```

Both of `devices` and `count` are output arguments of the `I1_GetDevices` function, so they are passed by reference (`ByRef`), not by value (`ByVal`). `I1_DeviceHandle` is a 32-bit pointer, so it is declared as `Long`, because `Long` is a 32-bit integer type. `I1_UInteger` is presumably an 32-bit unsigned int, so it is declared as `Long` as well. The `Variant` type is more complex than a simple integer value, so it is incorrect to declare the return type as a Variant.

One last point: `handles` is actually an array, so you may also try this declaration:

```
Public Declare Function I1_GetDevices Lib "C:\i1Pro.dll" _
    (ByRef handles as Long(), ByRef count as Long) As Long
```